# Elasticsearch error handling in onFailure (Async requests)

Tags: elasticsearch

For example when you make an async request in elasticsearch, the onFailure returns Exception. Is it appropriate to handle the exception as shown below.

```
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                Throwable[] throwables = e.getSuppressed();
                  for(Throwable throwable: throwables){
                    if (throwable instanceof ElasticsearchException) {
                        throw new ElasticsearchException("message");
                    } else if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
                        try {
                            throw new IOException("message");
                        } catch (IOException ioException) {
                            ioException.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }       
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using the [Future interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to handle the async request, and the get method will throw exception if any. Here's a snippet using reindex request as an example:

```
    PlainActionFuture<BulkByScrollResponse> future = new PlainActionFuture<>();
    ReindexRequest request = new ReindexRequest();
    request.setSourceIndices(sourceIndexName);
    request.setDestIndex(destIndexName);

    restHighLevelClient.reindexAsync(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT, future);

    try {
        BulkByScrollResponse response = future.actionGet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("The reindex job aborted: {}", ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e));
    }
```

And here's the [reference](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.4.0/org/elasticsearch/action/ActionFuture.html) of exceptions types thrown from the interface.